# It does not detect the top property in my code when the window is 1300px

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**Error does not recognize the top:**

Hello, my problem is that when the window is less than 1300px, the upper part does not apply: 100% only applies this condition if I update the page, on the contrary, if it is the other way around, ¿the same thing happens. How can i fix this.?

I leave the code so that you can test the error I am a newbie I hope you can help me. Cheers

```js
var open = document.getElementById("open");
var photo = document.getElementById("photo");

function mediaQueries(btn) {
  //Width: 1300px
  if (btn.matches) {
    //top 100% does not apply, left 100% still applies
    open.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      photo.style = "top: 100%";
    });
    open.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      photo.style = "top: 0";
    });
  } else {
    open.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      photo.style = "left: 100%";
    });
    open.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      photo.style = "left: 0";
    });
  }
}

var btn = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1300px)");
mediaQueries(btn);
btn.addListener(mediaQueries);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box-container {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  max-width: 450px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/pdnQfFn/black-and-white-1281562-640-min.jpg");
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px;
}
.box-container .box-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
.box-container .box-content h2 {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.box-container .box-content p {
  margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 19.2px;
  /*120%*/
}
.box-container .box-content button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  background: #5d08be;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box-container .box-content button:hover {
  background: #10960b;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.box-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.4s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Card effect</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box-container" id="open">
    <div class="box-content">
      <div class="txt">
        <h2>Articulos de Moda</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur                      adipisicing elit.
           Impedit, ullam assumenda. 
           Quibusdam, dolores? Atanimi
           rerum nobis velit necessitatibus qui.</p>
        <button>LEER MÁS</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zhm9qNd/girl-min.jpg" id="photo">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Matias, your question is pretty vague, I'm not sure what the "upper part" is or which "100%" you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your problem by adjusting the code in the box-container. Your image was at the top, however the div containing the image wasn't. I changed box-container to have a top of 0, and removed the max-width because you had already said the width should be 100%. You can adjust the code (like adding margin and padding) to your needs.

```js
var open = document.getElementById("open");
var photo = document.getElementById("photo");

function mediaQueries(btn) {
  //Width: 1300px
  if (btn.matches) {
    //top 100% does not apply, left 100% still applies
    open.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      photo.style = "top: 100%";
    });
    open.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      photo.style = "top: 0";
    });
  } else {
    open.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      photo.style = "left: 100%";
    });
    open.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      photo.style = "left: 0";
    });
  }
}

var btn = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1300px)");
mediaQueries(btn);
btn.addListener(mediaQueries);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box-container {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/pdnQfFn/black-and-white-1281562-640-min.jpg");
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px;
}
.box-container .box-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
.box-container .box-content h2 {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.box-container .box-content p {
  margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 19.2px;
  /*120%*/
}
.box-container .box-content button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  background: #5d08be;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box-container .box-content button:hover {
  background: #10960b;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.box-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.4s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Card effect</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box-container" id="open">
    <div class="box-content">
      <div class="txt">
        <h2>Articulos de Moda</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur                      adipisicing elit.
           Impedit, ullam assumenda. 
           Quibusdam, dolores? Atanimi
           rerum nobis velit necessitatibus qui.</p>
        <button>LEER MÁS</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zhm9qNd/girl-min.jpg" id="photo">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```